# Standard probability space, error in book "Integration and probability" by Paul Malliavin.

Tags: measure-theory

In the Encyclopedia of Mathematics article titled "[Standard probability space](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Standard_probability_space#Criticism)", under the section "Criticism", we can see the following:

> According to [Mal],
>
> - a measure is called separable if the corresponding L1 space is separable [Mal, Sect. IV.6.0];
> - every separable complete nonatomic probability space is isomorphic to [0,1] with Lebesgue measure [Mal, Sect. IV.6.4.2: "structure theorem (nonatomic case)"].
>
> The proof provides a measure preserving map from the given space to [0,1] that generates the given σ-algebra. However, such map is not necessarily an isomorphism. Its image must be of full outer measure, but not of full inner measure, which is a manifestation of the "image measure catastrophe" (see [KP, p. 94], [D, p. 1002]).
>
> Further, in [Mal, Sect. IV.6.4.3: "structure theorem (general case)"] it is claimed that every separable (as defined there) complete probability space is standard (as defined here), which is wrong, of course.*"

Question #1: Where I can find the correct statement and proof of the abovementioned theorem?

Question#2: Why statement  "*every separable (as defined there) complete probability space is standard (as defined here)*" is wrong?

---

[Mal]   Paul Malliavin, "Integration and probability", Springer-Verlag (1995).

[MR1335234](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1335234)   [Zbl 0874.28001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0874.28001)

[KP]    Joseph Kupka, Karel Prikry, "The measurability of uncountable unions", Amer. Math. Monthly 91 (1984), 85–97.   [MR0729548](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0729548)   [Zbl 0533.28010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0533.28010)

[D] R.M. Dudley, "Nonmetric compact spaces and nonmeasurable processes", Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 108 (1990), 1001–1005.   [MR0994775](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0994775)   [Zbl 0697.60037](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0697.60037)

Comment: can you give the actual link?

Comment: I gave the link.

Comment: But what is wrong with Malliavin's proof?